# Fortigate bandwidth monitoring

Tags: bandwidth, fortinet, bandwidth-measuring, fortigate

I have a Fortigate 200B with Forti OS 5.0.

How can I watch the total bandwidth being used by my unit both incoming and outgoing?

Thanks

Comment: The easiest way is creating a widget of interface bandwidth monitor in the GUI dashbord.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using Nagios and check_iftraffic plugin.
Much easier to configure.

Answer (score 2):

With an 'x' amount of ports, you'd want to ask yourself which NIC you'd like to get the stats for.   The Fortigate has a stat specific for anything that goes though it's fw service and that is:

```
[CLI] My_Forti_OS # get system performance firewall statistics
```

There is also a more generic 'system performance' command that will not only give you some valuable system-wide network and session information, but it will also show some cpu data and general stats for IPS/Virus-detection services, that command is:

```
[CLI] My_Forti_OS # get system performance status
```

Now, a more granular network interface command is available but it is 'per nic', not a live total statistic:

```
[CLI] My_Forti_OS # get hardware nic port5
```

If supported on the 200b, You could use the GUI to show a graph for each interface.  I usually don't like to do this however and option towards sending these types of info/data to an SNMP server like cacti.   You can do some really magic with this option ;)

Comment: How could I use the GUI to pop up a graph if this is a CLI ?

Comment: Also in all of those the one that seemed the most related was the second command.
It gives me Average Network Usage. But is that for ALL my interfaces because I only need Internet...?

Comment: In the GUI, you'd need to go to the dashboard and add a widget for 'interface history' but this is a per interface feature.  According to what you want, you're probably better off sending your log data to a server and manipulating it's input there.  No real good way to do it with the Fortigate without a FortiAnalyzer.

Comment: Actually that widget would have been exactly what I need had it NOT been removed from FortiOS 5.0 :-\
I have Session History, nothing more.
I guess I'll be using that NetFlow Analyzer. It comes with a trial.
Thanks for your help man.

Comment: I have 5.0.4 and it has it... of course, I'm using different hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [logging and reporting](http://docs.fortinet.com/fgt/handbook/50/fortigate-loggingreporting-50.pdf) at the [Fortigate Doc site](https://docs.fortigate.com).  Also, look at the FortiLog product.

There are many other options in this area as well, such as ntop, flow-inspector, bro, argus.  I use a combination of argus and flow-inspector.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this data with some great info on application/protocol/region (depending on what you're logging) using a free basic [FortiCloud](https://www.forticloud.com) account.